# How to fix InvocationTargetException javaFX Maven lib

Tags: maven, javafx

I am a newbie to javafx and I am currently working on a project with Maven lib using JavaFX. Although, after adding an anchor pane and a button with some ids, I ran into this error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: No controller specified.
/Users/kevintruong/maven-project/InventoryTracker/target/classes/com/flexus/InventoryTracker/primary.fxml:9

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2621)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$100(FXMLLoader.java:105)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.getControllerMethodHandle(FXMLLoader.java:565)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:607)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:778)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2838)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2557)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
    at com.flexus.InventoryTracker/com.flexus.InventoryTracker.App.loadFXML(App.java:31)
    at com.flexus.InventoryTracker/com.flexus.InventoryTracker.App.start(App.java:20)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
Exception running application com.flexus.InventoryTracker.App
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXRunMojo.java:525)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXRunMojo.java:487)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute(JavaFXRunMojo.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXRunMojo.java:525)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXRunMojo.java:487)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute(JavaFXRunMojo.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
```

My primary controller:

```
package com.flexus.InventoryTracker;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class PrimaryController {

    @FXML
    private Button signUp;

    @FXML
    void switchToSignUp() throws IOException {
        App.setRoot("primary");
    }

}
```

My main class:

```
package com.flexus.InventoryTracker;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {

    private static Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        scene = new Scene(loadFXML("primary"));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    static void setRoot(String fxml) throws IOException {
        scene.setRoot(loadFXML(fxml));
    }

    private static Parent loadFXML(String fxml) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource(fxml + ".fxml"));
        return fxmlLoader.load();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

My primary fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: #FDFEFE;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="signUp" layoutX="529.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#switchToSignUp" style="-fx-background-color: #FDFEFE;" text="Sign up" textFill="#3498db" underline="true" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

After hours of research, I still haven't found any solutions for this error yet. Does anybody have any ideas what I have done wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `InvocationTargetException` is never the root of the problem. That exception is thrown when a method is invoked via reflection but that method itself throws an exception. The exception thrown by the invoked-via-reflection method is wrapped by (i.e. the cause of) the `InvocationTargetException`. The [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/6395627) Q&A provides more information on stack traces and how to read them.

So if we look at the last `Caused by` in your stack trace, we see the fundamental error is:

```
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: No controller specified.
/Users/kevintruong/maven-project/InventoryTracker/target/classes/com/flexus/InventoryTracker/primary.fxml:9
```

<sup>***Note:** The output starting with "`[ERROR] Command execution failed.`" is from Maven, not your application.*</sup>

Now, specifying a controller class is not *always* required; however, in your FXML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" 
            minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" 
            style="-fx-background-color: #FDFEFE;" 
            xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="signUp" layoutX="529.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" 
              onAction="#switchToSignUp" style="-fx-background-color: #FDFEFE;" 
              text="Sign up" textFill="#3498db" underline="true" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

You define the `onAction` attribute for your `Button` element. This requires a controller to be specified where the controller has the corresponding method. I see you have a class named `PrimaryController` which has a `switchToSignUp()` method, so it appears you've simply forgotton to specify the controller in your FXML file. You just need to add that attribute to the root element:

```xml
<AnchorPane fx:controller="com.flexus.InventoryTracker.PrimaryController" ...>
    ...
</AnchorPane>
```

<sup>***Note:** Following [Java naming conventions](https://dzone.com/articles/whats-in-a-name-java-naming-conventions), package names should be all lowercase.*</sup>

If you're using *Scene Builder*, you can specify the controller by going to the "Document" section in the left panel, expand the "Controller" pane, and typing the controller class' name in the text field labeled "Controller class".

For more information about FXML, see [Introduction to FXML](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html).

Comment: Hi Slaw, thank you very much for your detailed explanation, it works perfectly!